# IntelliJ IDEA IDE for Android development

Tags: java, android, ide, intellij-idea

Does anyone have an experience with Android development with intelliJ IDEA IDE? Does it suit all the needs?

Comment: Subjective, since everyones needs will be different. Is there anything specific here you are looking for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IDEA is an excellent IDE overall.  Android support is quite good with the exception of the WYSIWYG layout editor which IDEA doesn't have.  This isn't a huge problem since I find that the one in Eclipse doesn't work half the time anyhow.

I've been using IDEA for a long time (many years) and happily pay for the commercial license.  I find the UI to be more intuitive and more productive than Eclipse.  Code completions are smarter, editing is generally smoother, debugging is a bit more reliable (though neither IDEA or Eclipse seems to have flawless integration with adb--probably adb problems).

Eclipse does have slightly better integration with some Android tools such as DDMS which can be hosted in a perspective in Eclipse.

If you find Eclipse confusing and frustrating to get started with, give IDEA a try.  IDE choices are highly personal so I can't promise you'll like it better, but since Android support is now included in the community edition of IDEA you've got nothing to lose but some time.

No, I don't work for JetBrains but as a long-time paying customer I can also vouch for the quality of their customer support.

Answer (score 4):

> Does it suit all the needs?

Yes it is!

You can develop android application using IntelliJ Community Edition which is free.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_android.html

Answer (score 1):

For develop android application a more suitable eclipse, because it has a profiler. Profiler in the IDEA does not work for Android platform.
A set of tools in IDEA for android yet insufficient.

I hope in the near future IDEA will be better....

Answer (score 1):

I'm using intensively Intellij IDEA for Android development - and to my opinion it's better than Eclipse. There are still some drawbacks:

1. It doesn't support ProGuard obfuscation for Android
2. For versions < 10 there were some minor bugs with respect to Android SDK 9

Comment: I just made a new android project in IntelliJ IDEA 10.0.2 EAP and it actually made a proguard.cfg file in the project.  Does this mean they recently added support?